# a specific error handling in bison

Tags: bison

Flex definition:

```
"view"  { return VIEW;}
"cell"  { return CELL;}
[A-Za-z]+ {
      yylval.strval=strdup(yytext);
      return ALPHA;
      }
[()]   {return yytext[0];}
```

My bison grammar:

```
static int len=10;
static char *allkeywords[10]=   {"view","acload","actual","after","alpha","and","annotate","apply","arc","array" };

cell:’(’ CELL ALPHA ’)’ { goal=$3;
                       flag=binary_search(allkeywords,len,goal);
                       if(flag) 
                        { 
                       yyerror("warnning: the component name is a keyword");
                       yyclearin;
                       yyerrok;
                       }                                                                    
            ;
int binary_search(const char *a[10], int len, char *goal)
  {    
   int low = 0;    
   int high = len - 1;    
   while(low <= high)    
    {        
     int middle = (low + high)/2;        
     if(strcmp (goal,a[middle])==0 )           
         return 1;        
       else if(strcmp (goal,a[middle]) < 0)        
          high = middle - 1;            
            else            
               low = middle + 1;    
 }    
 return 0;     
 }
```

My instructions:

```
bison -d -v bison.y
flex  flex.l 
gcc bison.tab.c lex.yy.c
```

For instance, the input stream is (cell view ), the word “view” is random monogram given by a user.Coincidentally, it is a keyword of EDIF file, and it also corresponds to ALPHA. I set that if the ALPHA given by user is a keyword, call yyerror function to warn, but the bison call yyerror itself. Its output is “zhouzhou:1.3-1.6:syntax error, unexpected CELL, expecting EDIF”, actually, I expect that it present” zhouzhou:1.3-1.6: warnning: the component name is a keyword”.
How to make bison not to call its yyerror , just do what I mean ?

Comment: The code is admirably short, but a little too short.  It isn't compilable because the `%%` section markers are missing (as are headers).  Sure, they can be filled in without too much difficulty, but when you're seeking help, it pays to make it easy for those who might help you.

Answer (score 1):

While you can code a grammar so that keywords are allowed as identifiers, doing so is unnatural and painfully hard.  Keywords are so called because you can't use them as identifiers.

#### Working `flex.l`

```
%{
#include "bison.tab.h"
%}

%%
"view"  { puts("VIEW"); return VIEW;}
"cell"  { puts("CELL"); return CELL;}
[A-Za-z]+ {
      yylval.strval=strdup(yytext);
      puts("ALPHA:");
      puts(yylval.strval);
      return ALPHA;
      }
[()]   {puts("PARENS"); return yytext[0];}  

.      { printf("SKIP: %d %c\n", yytext[0], yytext[0]); }

%%

int yywrap(void)
{
    return(1);
}
```

#### Working `bison.y`

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int binary_search(char **a, int len, char *goal);

static char *goal;
static int flag;
static int len=10;
static char *allkeywords[10]=   {"view", "acload", "actual", "after", "alpha", "and", "annotate", "apply", "arc", "array" };

%}

%union { char *strval; }

%token <strval> CELL
%token <strval> ALPHA
%token <strval> VIEW

%%

cell: '(' CELL ALPHA ')'
        {
            goal=$3;
            flag=binary_search(allkeywords, len, goal);
            if(flag) 
            { 
                printf("Before yyerror()\n");
                yyerror("warning: the component name is a keyword");
                printf("After yyerror()\nBefore yyclearin\n");
                yyclearin;
                printf("After yyclearin\nBefore yyerrok\n");
                yyerrok;
                printf("After yyerrok\n");
            }                                                                    
        }
    ;

%%

static int binary_search(char **a, int len, char *goal)
{    
    int low = 0;    
    int high = len - 1;    
    while(low <= high)    
    {        
        int middle = (low + high)/2;        
        if(strcmp (goal, a[middle])==0 )           
            return 1;        
        else if(strcmp (goal, a[middle]) < 0)        
            high = middle - 1;            
        else            
            low = middle + 1;    
    }    
    return 0;     
}

int main(void)
{
    int rc;
    yydebug = 1;
    setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IOLBF, 0);
    rc = yyparse();
    printf("== In main after yyparse() = %d\n", rc);
    return(0);
}
```

#### Build script for Mac OS X 10.8.2

```
set -x
bison -d -v bison.y &&
flex  flex.l  &&
gcc -DYYDEBUG bison.tab.c lex.yy.c -ly &&

a.out < data
```

#### Data file

```
(cell alpha)
```

#### Trace from running program

```
++ bison -d -v bison.y
++ flex flex.l
++ gcc -DYYDEBUG bison.tab.c lex.yy.c -ly
++ a.out
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: PARENS
Next token is token '(' ()
Shifting token '(' ()
Entering state 1
Reading a token: CELL
Next token is token CELL ()
Shifting token CELL ()
Entering state 4
Reading a token: SKIP: 32  
ALPHA:
alpha
Next token is token ALPHA ()
Shifting token ALPHA ()
Entering state 6
Reading a token: PARENS
Next token is token ')' ()
Shifting token ')' ()
Entering state 7
Reducing stack by rule 3 (line 29):
   $1 = token '(' ()
   $2 = token CELL ()
   $3 = token ALPHA ()
   $4 = token ')' ()
Before yyerror()
warning: the component name is a keyword
After yyerror()
Before yyclearin
After yyclearin
Before yyerrok
After yyerrok
-> $$ = nterm cell ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 3
Reducing stack by rule 2 (line 25):
   $1 = nterm cell ()
Stack now 0
== In main after yyparse() = 0
```

Notice how the code returns successfully to the `main()` function once and does not call `yyerror()`.